# How can I check dependency list for a deb package

Tags: package-management, software-installation, deb

How can I check dependency list for a deb package. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and I have backed up all deb packages from `var/cache/apt/archives`. I want to format my pc and re-install selected applications only. Also how can I get the list of installed packages and dependencies.

Comment: For your second question see http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Comment: For the complete list of installed packages use `dpkg --get-selections | sed -n 's/[[:space:]]install$//p'`

Answer (score 142, accepted):

In addition to the `dpkg` method, you can check the dependencies of packages in the repository:

```
apt-cache depends package-name
```

**EDIT** Updated with @Tino's recommendation. @Tigran's comment no longer applies.

---

## depends VS rdepends

- apt-cache `depends` package-name
  //show package-name depends on who
- apt-cache `rdepends` package-name
  //show who depends on package-name

### depends

```
$ apt-cache depends vim-runtime
vim-runtime
  Breaks: vim-tiny
 |Recommends: vim
    vim-athena
    vim-gtk
    vim-gtk3
    vim-nox
 |Recommends: vim-gtk
 |Recommends: vim-gtk3
 |Recommends: vim-athena
 |Recommends: vim-nox
  Recommends: vim-tiny
  Enhances: vim-tiny
```

### rdepends

```
$ apt-cache rdepends vim-runtime
vim-runtime
Reverse Depends:
  vim
  vim
  vim-nox
  vim-gtk
  vim-athena
  vim-gtk3
  vim
  vim-nox
  vim-gtk
  vim-athena
  vim-gtk3
```

Comment: Note: this only works if the package is already installed.

Comment: @TigranSaluev Note that `dpkg -I package` only works for installed packages.  `apt-cache` works for all packages which are known after you have done `apt-get update`.

Comment: `apt-cache depends package` is a better way, in that case, as `showpkg` does not tell if a dependency is a recommend, conflict etc., so it is a bit puzzling.  For a script which does `depends` combined with `showpkg` see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/362866/23450

Comment: `apt-cache depends` operates on only the candidate package from your sources, not the specific package version you have installed. Can be confusing if your apt repo supports multiple versions. In which case `apt-cache depends package-name=VERSION` seems to be the only option.

Comment: dpkg -I package worked for deb file just copied from another computer (actually after apt failed to install it).

Answer (score 148):

This will show you all the information about the package:

```
dpkg -I package.deb
```

Comment: Don't forget to put `/var/cache/apt/archives/` before the package name and use tab completion to find the full package name with version, e.g. `dpkg -I /var/cache/apt/archives/elasticsearch_2.4.4_all.deb`.

Comment: I don't see any dependency information

Comment: You could add that the package can be obtained without (re)installing it (which is probably a popular use case) with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall --download-only [package name]`.

Comment: Note that this (or dpkg-deb as reported elsewhere) will only list the package's self-reported dependencies.  It does not guarantee that if you install everything listed as a dependency, that you will have everything needed to make the package functional.   Packages (especially 3rd party ones) typically assume some level of base system components not listed in their dependencies.

Comment: This works perfectly on my Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: FWIW, `-I` stands for `--info`. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg.1.html

Answer (score 9):

## For 14.04 and later:

`dpkg` doesn't have the `-I` any more and you have to use `dpkg-deb` to show package information including dependencies:

```
dpkg-deb -I package.deb
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.04, my dpkg does have an option "-I" (version 1.19.6).

Comment: My dpkg (v1.21.1) on Ubuntu Jammy 22.04 has `-I`

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is very old, but it is possible. I also had to dig through StackOverflow/AskUbuntu for ALL of this.

This ONLY SHOWS what depends are in the first package. Not all.

There might be some duplicates in the script methods but you can probably filter them out by doing this:

```bsh
COMMAND | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -d | xargs
```

Here are the methods:

### In a script

```bsh
dpkg-deb -I <The .deb> | grep -E "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | tr -d "|," | sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" | tr -d "()" | tr " " "\n" | grep -Ev "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | xargs
```

### In a script, but not downloaded (remote)

```bsh
apt-cache show <The package name> | grep -E "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | tr -d "|," | sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" | tr -d "()" | tr " " "\n" | grep -Ev "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | xargs
```

### Human readable

```bsh
dpkg-deb -I <The .deb> | grep -E --color=none "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends"
```

### Human readable (remote)

```bsh
apt-cache show <The package name> | grep -E --color=none "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends"
```

### Get amount of dependencies

```bsh
dpkg-deb -I <The .deb> | grep -E "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | tr -d "|," | sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" | tr -d "()" | tr " " "\n" | grep -Ev "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | xargs | tr " " "\n" | wc -l
```

### Get amount of dependencies (remote)

```bsh
apt-cache show <The package name> | grep -E "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | tr -d "|," | sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" | tr -d "()" | tr " " "\n" | grep -Ev "Depends|Recommends|Suggests|Pre\-Depends" | xargs | tr " " "\n" | wc -l
```

Comment: Nice set of commands you might want to split ```\``` those long ones for readability, but leave it up to you.

Comment: using `dpkg-deb --showformat` will shorten the command considerably, e.g., `dpkg-deb --show --showformat='${Depends} ${Recommends} ${Suggests} ${Pre-Depends}\n' bash_5.1-2_amd64.deb | sed -r 's/ \([^()]*\),?//g'`

Comment: this doesn't seem like it works or else I don't understand what i'm looking at. If I `apt depends curl` I get `libc6`, `libcurl`, `zlib1g`. If I `apt depends libc6` I get `libgcc-s1` and `libcyrpt1`. But if I use your scripts those 2nd levels are not appearing. (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: @gman It worked on Xubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 3):

`apt-cache depends [Package-Name]` will work as well. Although if you source the `.deb` package from outside your sources list, things like 
`apt-cache showpkg [Package-Name] && apt-cache depends [Package-Name]` might show outdated info or might not sync with the actual installed package hence 
`dpkg -I [Package-Name]` would work best in that case.

Answer (score 1):

For a specific package version:

```
apt-cache show <package_name>=<version>
```

To find available versions: [How can I check the available version of a package in the repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340530/how-can-i-check-the-available-version-of-a-package-in-the-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

In case you have the uninstalled package (usually downloaded manually from outside a repository), you need to use **dpkg**. The following command will show a summary of the package informations, including it's dependencies:

```
dpkg --info [package name]
```

In case the package is already installed on your machine (originated from the repository or from a manual download), or is not installed but is available in the repository, you can use **apt**. The following command will show only the list of it's dependencies.

```
apt depends [package name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sloppy, and probably not very encompassing post-processing you can do to `dpkg -I` output to get dependency items as a list:

Condensed for computers

```
# dpkg -I package.deb | python -c "import sys, re; t=re.split(r'\n(?= ?[\w]+:)|:', sys.stdin.read()); print '\n'.join([i.strip() for i in {key.strip(): value.strip() for key, value in zip(t[::2], t[1::2])}['Depends'].split(',')])"
#
```

Expanded for humans:

```
dpkg -I package.deb | python -c "
    import sys, re;
    # Split keys and values into pairs (zipped together later)
    t=re.split(
        r'\n(?= ?[\w]+:)|:', 
        sys.stdin.read()
    ); 
    # Newline separate each dependency
    print '\n'.join([
        # Trim each dependency value
        i.strip() for i in {
            # Build assoc array from package metadata
            key.strip(): value.strip() 
            for key, value in zip(t[::2], t[1::2])
        }['Depends'].split(',')
    ])
"
```

Comment: This will echo the packages which depend on 'foo.deb' and have yet to be installed: dpkg -I foo.deb | for i in $(awk -F', ' '/Depends: /{gsub(/: /, ", "); for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { gsub(/ .*$/, "", $(i)); printf("%s\n", $(i)); } }'); do dpkg -s $i &> /dev/null || echo $i; done | tr '\n' ' '

Comment: @GregoryBurd, Feel free to edit my answer/psot all you like, I posted it as  community wiki for this reason ^u^

Comment: When I run this command on elasticsearch, it emits `libc6\nadduser\n Installed-Size\n`. That is, it seems to be matching more than just the Depends line.