# How can I check the available version of a package in the repositories?

Tags: package-management

How can I check the version of the available package in the Ubuntu repositories without installing it?

Answer (score 470, accepted):

Use the command:

```
apt-cache policy <packageName>
```

This gives you information of all available package versions.

Example:

```
alaa@aa-lu:~$ apt-cache policy vlc
vlc:
  Installed: 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
  Candidate: 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 0
        500 http://ae.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0.6-1 0
        500 http://ae.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe i386 Packages
```

- From the output, you can see that there are two versions available: `2.0.8-0ubuntu0.13.04.1` and `2.0.6-1`. It also tells you which repositories they are coming from.
- `Installed:` tells you the version you have installed. If you don't have the package installed, you'll see `(none)`.
- `Candidate:` is the version that will be installed if you use `apt-get install vlc`. If you want to install the other version, you would do `apt-get install vlc=2.0.6-1`.

Answer (score 39):

Go to [**packages.ubuntu.com**](http://packages.ubuntu.com), fill in the search form and get a nice view of the package including the version.

---

[image]

---

Hit search, then:

---

[image]

---

#### Additional benefits

- Will also list versions of packages for other versions of Ubuntu. Eg. if you want to know about the version of the package in Raring (13.04), but your system still has Precise (12.04), then this will provide a way to find it out.
- You don't even need Ubuntu to be installed.

Biggest downside is that it won't list the versions of other repositories you possible have installed, such as PPAs. You will then need the [`apt-cache policy` approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/340536/88802) as already posted.

#### Pro tip

Take the shortcut - just browse to `http://packages.ubuntu.com/packagename` and replace `packagename` with the name of the package you want to query.

Answer (score 29):

```
apt-cache madison <packageName>
```

It also gives information about all available package versions in the repositories. This command output had the syntax like this:

```
packageName | Version | Repository
```

> apt-cache's madison command attempts to mimic the output format and a
>   subset of the functionality of the Debian archive management tool,
>   madison. It displays available versions of a package in a tabular
>   format. Unlike the original madison, it can only display information
>   for the architecture for which APT has retrieved package lists
>   (APT::Architecture).

**Example:**

```
$ apt-cache madison chromium-browser
chromium-browser | 32.0.1700.102-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20140128.970.1 | http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
chromium-browser | 32.0.1700.102-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20140128.970.1 | http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/ saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages
chromium-browser | 29.0.1547.65-0ubuntu2 | http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
chromium-browser | 29.0.1547.65-0ubuntu2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
chromium-browser | 29.0.1547.65-0ubuntu2 | http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/ saucy/universe Sources
chromium-browser | 32.0.1700.102-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20140128.970.1 | http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe Sources
chromium-browser | 32.0.1700.102-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~20140128.970.1 | http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu/ saucy-security/universe Sources
chromium-browser | 29.0.1547.65-0ubuntu2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe Sources
chromium-browser | 29.0.1547.65-0ubuntu2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe Sources
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply, the output is a lot more readable and workable with scripts than with `apt-cache policy`

Answer (score 11):

`apt-cache show` or `aptitude show` gives you a lot of information about a package from your repositories (even if this is installed or not), including the version. If you are interested only about version, use:

```
apt-cache show <packageName> | grep Version
```

or

```
aptitude show <packageName> | grep Version
```

If a package is available in several versions, you will see this. To see only the last version, use:

```
apt-cache show <packageName> | grep Version | head -1
```

You can not have any doubts with the above command.

Answer (score 10):

Open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  and then type as

```
apt-cache showpkg <package_name>
```

Then it will give you information about whats the available version.

for example:

```
jai@frank-Jai:~$ apt-cache showpkg chromium
Package: chromium
Versions: 

Reverse Depends: 
  mozplugger,chromium 10.0.648.114~r75702-1~
  chromium-bsu,chromium 0.9.14
  chromium-bsu,chromium 0.9.14
Dependencies: 
Provides: 
Reverse Provides: 
jai@frank-Jai:~$
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such a package named only "chromium". Therefore `apt-cache show` is more practical in this sense.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu  chromium is a browser.

Comment: Yes, you have right, but the name of the package is `chromium-browser`. You can check with `apt-cache search chromium`. It's the 5th line from the output :)

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-cache policy <PackageName> | grep Candidate | cut -d ':' -f 3 | cut -d '-' -f 1
```

Comment: Would be nice if you would edit your answer to include a brief description what your command and its sub parts do, so future readers may get some insight, not everyone is savvy enough to understand what you do there. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
sudo apt-get -s install --only-upgrade <package-name>
```

The above method only works if run with sudo.

Comment: I don't think you need sudo for this, since you're just simulating (`-s`)

Comment: You do if the user you're running the command as doesn't have read access to the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/  Same as if you run apt-cache policy <pkg name>  In my case, I had to run with sudo