# list of package versions by ubuntu releases?

Tags: package-management

is there a page that lists package versions that are in past and current versions of ubuntu?  for example, say that I want to find out which versions of the web stack (nginx, apache, php, perl, mariadb, mysql) were or are in the 12.04, 14.04, 15.04, and 15.10 beta, and I don't yet have these installed, where would I find this information?  answer to follow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the available version of a package in the repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340530/how-can-i-check-the-available-version-of-a-package-in-the-repositories)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know default software version for all ubuntu software for a specific ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038567/how-to-know-default-software-version-for-all-ubuntu-software-for-a-specific-ubun)

Answer (score 1):

- go to page [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). this is Ubuntu official
  packages website.
- type package name in search box and select architecture and version
  of Ubuntu and click on search
- after clicking on search there will be `Search in specific suite` using that you can switch different version
- there you can get package description , repository name etc.

Answer (score 0):

http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu

provides a nice table of key packages in different versions.