# What is the version of Postgres sql shipped with Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04

We are planning for Ubuntu OS upgrade next year, wanted to know which version of Postgres is supported by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the available version of a package in the repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340530/how-can-i-check-the-available-version-of-a-package-in-the-repositories)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know default software version for all ubuntu software for a specific ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038567/how-to-know-default-software-version-for-all-ubuntu-software-for-a-specific-ubun)

Answer (score 3):

This you can find [using the package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) on Ubuntu's website.

Answer (score 0):

The default version of postgresql-10 in Ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10 is version 10.5. The default version of postgresql-11 is version 11.2 in Ubuntu 19.04 and version 11.5 in Ubuntu 19.10. postgresql-common is a dependency of postgresql-10. The default version of postgresql-12 is version 12.2 in Ubuntu 20.04

Results of `dpkg --list | grep -i postgres`

```
ii  libpq5:amd64               10.5-0ubuntu0.18.04    amd64    PostgreSQL C client library
ii  postgresql-10              10.5-0ubuntu0.18.04    amd64    object-relational SQL database, version 10 server
ii  postgresql-client-10       10.5-0ubuntu0.18.04    amd64    front-end programs for PostgreSQL 10
ii  postgresql-client-common   190                    all      manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common          190                    all      PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
```

Comment: Did you checked in your Ubuntu 18 server instance. If you post dpkg —list | grep -i Postgres will be very helpful. thank you

Comment: @user4 why? He is correct and so is vidarlo.  See the package list vidarlo linked to.  By the way: for this kind of software I would use their postgres version myself. They got a PPA.

Answer (score 0):

I use Postgres on a Ubuntu 18.04 server for map generation. My undertanding is that Ubuntu server does not come with Postgres installed by default and that you can choose to install whichever version suits your needs with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-xx
```

where *xx* is the version. I used version 10, so that would be:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10
```