# Downgrade Mesa Drivers

Tags: drivers, steam, downgrade, mesa

I see a ton of references as to how to UPGRADE your Mesa drivers using PPAs. However, is there a way to DOWNGRADE easily? For example, I currently have Mesa 17.1.3 installed but would like the ability to revert to Mesa 11.2 and back if necessary.

I'll notice games on Steam have specific Mesa versions in their requirements page and would like to be able to install different versions of the driver to accommodate for stability while playing that game. I'm stumbling across multiple bugs and the feedback I get from the support team is "Try Mesa x.x.x" (helpful, right?).

Comment: Abstractly, yes. However, I'm looking for some specifics. Specifically how to downgrade MESA drivers. sudo apt-get install mesa<???> =<package-version-number>. How can you get a list of all versions the ubuntu repository contains? Is there a PPA that has a history of all the older Mesa drivers? Etc. I'm not finding any good resources.

Comment: Check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/340530/how-can-i-check-the-available-version-of-a-package-in-the-repositories