# How to find current version of Gnome for Ubuntu 18.04 from internet?

Tags: apt, gnome, internet, versions

I'm writing this in Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. I'm looking at Gnome Extensions for Ubuntu 18.04 that work with Gnome version 3.24 and breaks with version 3.26.

How can I find out using browser (google search doesn't tell me), `apt list | grep ...` or other means what version of Gnome Ubuntu 18.04 is using today?

Rebooting every time I want to know something about a version I haven't booted is inconvenient.

---

**Test Results:**

```
zcat /dev/nvme0n1p10/usr/share/doc/gnome-session-bin/changelog.Debian.gz | head -n1
gzip: /dev/nvme0n1p10/usr/share/doc/gnome-session-bin/changelog.Debian.gz: Not a directory
```

**Important Note:** I do not have 18.04 installed. I have 18.04 Unity installed. I want to know current known version would be installed so I can research bugs before installation.

---

**EDIT:** I'm not looking for the Gnome version of the current booted partition (as the duplicate candidate does) using:

```
$ apt-cache policy gnome-shell
gnome-shell:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.18.5-0ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
     3.18.5-0ubuntu0.3 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     3.18.4-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

I'm looking for the gnome version for a partition that needs to be mounted first (18.04). Or simply a link to a website containing the current version numbers as of today for 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, etc.

Comment: "simply a link to a website containing the current version numbers as of today for 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, etc." ... that's pretty much what the second answer to the dupe is.

Comment: gnome-shell --version

Comment: @Aravind Two problems: **1.** Gnome Shell isn't installed on my 16.04.5 LTS which I've booted with so command doesn't work. **2.** I want to know which version is available for 18.04 and I would like to mount that partition without rebooting machine.

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/a/340635/175814 not achieve what you want?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Your link hits the nail on the head. Thank you. (I also believe this is what Muru was referring to a few days ago).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS uses GNOME 3.28 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS uses GNOME 3.18.

If you have installed GNOME as deb-packages, then you can visit [`packages.ubuntu.com` and get info about `gnome-session-bin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=gnome-session-bin):

> - trusty (14.04LTS) (gnome): GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
>     3.9.90-0ubuntu12: amd64
> - trusty-updates (gnome): GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
>     3.9.90-0ubuntu12.1: amd64
> - xenial (16.04LTS) (gnome): GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
>     3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1: amd64
> - xenial-updates (gnome): GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
>     3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.2: amd64
> - bionic (18.04LTS) (gnome): GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
>     3.28.1-0ubuntu2: amd64
> - bionic-updates (gnome): GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
>     3.28.1-0ubuntu3: amd64
> - eoan (19.10) (gnome): GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
>     3.34.1-1ubuntu2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
> - focal (20.04LTS) (gnome): GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
>     3.36.0-2ubuntu1: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x

On installed system you can use one of

```
dpkg -l gnome-session-bin
apt list gnome-session-bin | grep gnome
```

or directly view corresponding changelog files:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

  ```
  $ zcat /usr/share/doc/gnome-session-bin/changelog.Debian.gz | head -n1
  gnome-session (3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.2) xenial; urgency=medium
  ```
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:

  ```
  $ zcat /usr/share/doc/gnome-session-bin/changelog.Debian.gz | head -n1
  gnome-session (3.28.1-0ubuntu3) bionic; urgency=medium
  ```
- any current Ubuntu (to be mounted):

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
  zcat /mnt/usr/share/doc/gnome-session-bin/changelog.Debian.gz | head -n1
  ```

For Snap-packaged GNOME you can use `snap list` (below is example for 18.04 LTS):

```
$ snap list | grep gnome
gnome-3-26-1604       3.26.0     64    stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-calculator      3.28.1     170   stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-characters      3.28.2     96    stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-logs            3.28.2     34    stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-system-monitor  3.26.0     41    stable/…  canonical  -
```

Comment: So it seems like the answer is. When booted into 16.04, mount 18.04 partition as `/mnt/18.04` and then type: `zcat /mnt/18.04/usr/share/doc/gnome-session-bin/changelog.Debian.gz | head -n1`

Comment: Added to the answer. While writing I mean mounting but forget to mention :)

Comment: I tested the command and updated my question with results. It was not successful possibly because I'm using Ubuntu **Unity 18.04**. Thanks.

Comment: As they've closed the question as a duplicate (even though I disagree) I'm accepting your answer because **1.** it is a good answer and **2.** even if a perfect answer is available it can no longer be posted on this closed question.

Comment: Nominated for reopen. Thank you here and with Caja+Nautilus :)