# apt-get install certain version

Tags: apt, software-installation, postgresql

I have this:

```
 # apt-get update
 # apt-get install -y postgresql-client=11.2
```

and I get

> E: Version '11.2' for 'postgresql-client' was not found

but if I remove the version from the install and I try to run pg_dump command, I get:

> stderr: pg_dump: server version: 11.2; pg_dump version: 10.10 (Ubuntu
>   10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

seems weird that there is no client version of the same value. What can I do to find the closest possible client-lib version?

Comment: Please check this link on how to search for available package versions https://askubuntu.com/questions/340530/how-can-i-check-the-available-version-of-a-package-in-the-repositories

Answer (score 1):

Use
`apt-cache policy <packagename>` to find the available versions.
Next use

```
sudo apt install <packagename>=<version string>
```

to install that specific version.