# What's the default Python version in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python3, 20.04, versions

What's the default Python 3 version in the new Ubuntu 20.04? Is it still 3.6 or the latest Python 3.8?

I'm developing a Python program that I later want to run on the new Ubuntu 20.04. I'm unsure if I can use the latest Python 3.8 syntax. I don't have Ubuntu 20.04 installed yet to quickly check it, and I couldn't easily find the answer to this question on Google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check the available version of a package in the repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340530/how-can-i-check-the-available-version-of-a-package-in-the-repositories). See the [second answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/340635/6316009).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 has Python 3.8.2 as the default version. Python 2.7 has been moved to universe and is not included by default in any new installs.  [Official Release Notes about Python](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Python3_by_default)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to find the default Python 3 version of *any* Ubuntu release, you can run the command

```
rmadison python3
```

```
 python3 | 3.2.3-0ubuntu1   | precise         | all
 python3 | 3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2 | precise-updates | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 python3 | 3.4.0-0ubuntu2   | trusty          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 python3 | 3.5.1-3          | xenial          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 python3 | 3.6.5-3          | bionic          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 python3 | 3.6.7-1~18.04    | bionic-updates  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 python3 | 3.8.2-0ubuntu2   | focal           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 python3 | 3.8.6-0ubuntu1   | groovy          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

Alternatively, check the package

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all

For groovy (Ubuntu 20.10), it's Python 3.8.6:

[image]

Comment: A faster way of doing the same thing is to run the following command in a terminal: `rmadison python3`. In Ubuntu 20.04 it returns `python3 | 3.8.2-0ubuntu2`

Comment: This link is now working better for me: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Ubuntu 20.04 release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes):

> Ubuntu 20.04 LTS comes with a refreshed state-of-the-art toolchain including new upstream releases of glibc 2.31, OpenJDK 11, rustc 1.41, GCC 9.3, Python 3.8.2, ruby 2.7.0, php 7.4, perl 5.30 and golang 1.13.

Answer (score 4):

**Manifest file**

Another thing you can do for any Ubuntu version and any package is to check the manifest file which lists all preinstalled packages in the image: https://web.archive.org/web/20200508223720/https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.manifest

It contains `python3.8` but nothing that seems python2 related.

See also: [How do I list the default installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48886/how-do-i-list-the-default-installed-packages)

Comment: The link to the manifest is dead, https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest works.