# "An error occurred when checking for updates" and terminal won't open following Python fiddling

Tags: python, 20.04

I am currently getting a error in the top right of the bar at the top of the screen in the form of a red circle with a white line saying upon clicking "An error occurred when checking for updates" with some options in a drop down menu.
I have also noticed terminal doesn't open by clicking the icon though will open by opening a file in terminal.

I believe this is due to messing about with python trying to get eclipse pydev to work with python3.8 instead of python2.something.
python -V returns python3.6.11 though while faffing about I may have been trying to get it to be switch to python3.7
while looking at other forum posts I also changed the gnome-terminal from #!/usr/bin/python3 to #!/usr/bin/python3.6

I am not very experienced at this kind of computer stuff and realise this is caused by me not understanding what I'm doing.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and recently went straight from 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04. Also I read somewhere that 20.04 should have python3.8 as default, is this right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes [3.8.x is the default on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1232812/411468). The [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Python3_by_default) have some interesting info likely useful for you.
Changing the shebang in any scripts you're not developing is highly not recommended -- they tend to be stable with a certain version and fail hard with others. If you want to call a script with a specific version of Python then just invoke it like that, e.g. call the script with `python3.6` in your case. Or 3.7 if you want that. Also may be good to use a virtualenv or pyenv.

Comment: Would be a good idea to change the shebang of `gnome-terminal` back to the original value. Also, if you look back at your history (provided it's all still there)  you can see what you've done and try to undo it to return to default *or* just do a fresh install if you can still backup any important data first. The command `history -a` will flush the current terminal session's history without having to exit.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help