# How do I check Apparmor version?

Tags: package-management, apparmor

How can I check the version of the installed Apparmor on a Linux system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check the available version of a package in the repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340530/how-can-i-check-the-available-version-of-a-package-in-the-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

Use `dpkg -l`:

```
dpkg -l apparmor | tee
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version           Architecture Description
+++-==============-=================-============-======================================
ii  apparmor       2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1 amd64        user-space parser utility for AppArmor
```