# How to check netplan version?

Tags: netplan

I cannot find the way how to check which release of Netplan runs on my Ubuntu 22.04.

There is a [new release](https://github.com/canonical/netplan/releases/tag/0.107), which I would need, but I'm pretty new to Linux and do not know how to upgrade it. It's not like a "usual" application which is installed by apt.

Can you help me out?

Comment: You can also check the [Package Index](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=netplan.io) to see which version of netplan is packaged for each version of Ubuntu. That said, there's really no point. Ubuntu's stable release update policy means that you will basically never see a new version of it in a given Ubuntu release, except via backports, which are rather rare. Either you'll have to find a PPA which packages the new release for Ubuntu, or use version of Ubuntu which has the new release packaged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a way that netplan displays a version number itself, however you can query the package system to find out.

You can check the available/installed packages as provided in this answer:
https://askubuntu.com/a/340536/862145

It is important to know that the package name is **netplan.io**

```
user@lab:~$ apt policy netplan.io
netplan.io:
  Installed: 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2
  Candidate: 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.99-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
user@lab:~$
```

*Installed* shows you the version you have installed, or lists (none)

*Candidate* lists the version available via apt install

This is from this question:
[How can I check the available version of a package in the repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340530/how-can-i-check-the-available-version-of-a-package-in-the-repositories)

Comment: An added benefit of this is that you can see the version development from the first release of your distro. Here, the development from 0.99 to 0.104 in the period, not counting minor patches.