# How to find all dependent (dependency walker) packages before installing a .deb file?

Tags: kernel, package-management

When installing Ubuntu Core 13.10 according to the instructions at [wiki.ubuntu.com/Core/InstallationExample](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core/InstallationExample), step 5 says that Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise Pangolin" development **kernel requires** the 'wireless-crda' package. This wiki suggest to have a look at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com). However the [precise/linux-image-3.8.0-37-generic page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux-image-3.8.0-37-generic)  doesn't even mention the 'wireless-crda' package at all.

After reading the Ask Ubuntu articles for 'download +kernel +packages +deb', ['"depends on" +kernel +packages'](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22depends%20on%22%20%2bkernel%20%2bpackages), ['wireless-crda'](https://askubuntu.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=wireless-crda) and "[How to automatically fetch missing dependencies when installing software from .deb?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58202/how-to-automatically-fetch-missing-dependencies-when-installing-software-from-d)" I still don't know how to figure out **all** dependent packages.

Update#1

The answers from [How can I check dependency list for a deb package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80655/how-can-i-check-dependency-list-for-a-deb-package)

#### 1. `apt-cache showpkg linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic`

doesn't output a 'wireless-crda' dependency:

```
Reverse Depends: 
  linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic:i386,linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic
  linux-signed-image-3.11.0-18-generic,linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic 3.11.0-18.32
  linux-image-virtual,linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic
  linux-image-generic,linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic,linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic
Dependencies: 
3.11.0-18.32 - initramfs-tools (2 0.36ubuntu6) module-init-tools (2 3.3-pre11-4ubuntu3) dpkg (2 1.10.24) fdutils (0 (null)) linux-doc-3.11.0 (16 (null)) linux-source-3.11.0 (0 (null)) linux-tools (0 (null)) linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic (0 (null)) grub-pc (16 (null)) grub-efi-amd64 (16 (null)) grub-efi-ia32 (16 (null)) grub (16 (null)) lilo (2 19.1) hotplug (3 0.0.20040105-1) hotplug:i386 (3 0.0.20040105-1) linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic:i386 (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
3.11.0-18.32 - redhat-cluster-modules linux-image-3.0 linux-image kvm-api-4 ivtv-modules fuse-module 
Reverse Provides:
```

#### 2. `dpkg -I linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic_3.11.0-18.32_amd64.deb`

also doesn't output a 'wireless-crda' dependency:

```
Depends: initramfs-tools (>= 0.36ubuntu6), module-init-tools (>= 3.3-pre11-4ubuntu3)
 Recommends: grub-pc | grub-efi-amd64 | grub-efi-ia32 | grub | lilo (>= 19.1)
 Suggests: fdutils, linux-doc-3.11.0 | linux-source-3.11.0, linux-tools, linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic
 Conflicts: hotplug (<< 0.0.20040105-1)
 Provides: fuse-module, ivtv-modules, kvm-api-4, linux-image, linux-image-3.0, redhat-cluster-modules
```

When installing the kernel through `apt-get install linux-{headers,image}-generic` there is a depending 'wireless-crda' package.

Question:

How to find out - before actually installing the Ubuntu kernel .deb file - **all** dependent packages that need to be installed?

Comment: @Ahmadgeo The answers in http://askubuntu.com/questions/80655/how-can-i-check-dependency-list-for-a-deb-package don't give me a clue how the link to the wireless-cdma package exists in the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com). The `apt-get install linux-{headers,image}-generic` command installs two packages:

1. [linux-headers-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/linux-headers-generic)
2. [linux-image-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/linux-image-generic)

### 1. linux-headers-generic

depends on [linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic), which depends on:

1. [libc6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libc6), which depends on [libgcc1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libgcc1)
2. [linux-headers-3.11.0-18](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/linux-headers-3.11.0-18), which depends on [coreutils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/coreutils)

### 2. linux-image-generic

depends on:

1. [linux-firmware](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/linux-firmware)
2. [linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic)
3. [linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic)

#### 2.2. linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic

depends on:

1. [dpkg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/dpkg)
2. [initramfs-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/initramfs-tools)
3. [module-init-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/module-init-tools)

#### 2.3. linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic

depends on:

1. [crda](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/crda) or [wireless-crda](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/wireless-crda)
2. [linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic)

And there you have found how the kernel .deb file is depending upon wireless-crda.

Answer (score 0):

With `apt-cache showpkg pkg-name1` or `dpkg -I pkg-name1_version.deb` you can get the list of the dependencies for the *pkg-name1*. But one of the dependency package to *pkg-name1* say *pkg-name2* may depend on some other package *pkg-name3* and so on.

So you'll need to not only know the *pkg-name1*'s dependencies but also for their dependencies' dependencies ... ... and then you can download the packages (that are not already installed in your system.)

Comment: So with neither `apt-cache` nor `dpkg` there is an option to output a walk down of **all** dependencies, including the dependencies of dependant packages (dependency walker), which are not already met (=installed)?

Comment: Just an idea - a possible way would be creating a script to generate the entire dependency walker list with `apt-cache` and filter out those packages with an _installed_ state as indicated by `apt-get`. (but again that would be too much to ask from me..)