# Obs-studio is installing VLC without permission

Tags: vlc, obs-studio

My laptop is running on ubuntu 20.04. I installed obs studio with `sudo apt install obs-studio`. Now vlc app is installed with it.It don't even ask for any permission.Did i just installed anything bad for my system ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check dependency list for a deb package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80655/how-can-i-check-dependency-list-for-a-deb-package)

Answer (score 3):

Correction: Ubuntu *did* ask your permission and you simply missed the fact that VLC and some of its libraries were going to be installed.

This is what you would have seen after typing `sudo apt install obs-studio`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaribb24-0 libavdevice58 libcddb2 libdc1394-25 libdca0 libdvbpsi10 libdvdnav4 libebml5 libfaad2 libixml10 libkate1 liblua5.2-0 libluajit-5.1-2
  libluajit-5.1-common libmad0 libmatroska7 libmbedcrypto3 libmbedtls12 libmbedx509-0 libmpcdec6 libobs0 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenmpt-modplug1
  libplacebo72 libproxy-tools libqt5svg5 libqt5x11extras5 libqt5xml5 libresid-builder0c2a libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libsdl2-2.0-0 libsidplay2
  libsndio7.0 libspatialaudio0 libssh2-1 libupnp13 libva-wayland2 libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore9 libxcb-composite0 obs-plugins vlc vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n
  vlc-plugin-access-extra vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-output vlc-plugin-video-splitter
  vlc-plugin-visualization
Suggested packages:
  libdvdcss2 libportaudio2 sndiod v4l2loopback-dkms vlc-plugin-fluidsynth vlc-plugin-jack vlc-plugin-svg
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libaribb24-0 libavdevice58 libcddb2 libdc1394-25 libdca0 libdvbpsi10 libdvdnav4 libebml5 libfaad2 libixml10 libkate1 liblua5.2-0 libluajit-5.1-2
  libluajit-5.1-common libmad0 libmatroska7 libmbedcrypto3 libmbedtls12 libmbedx509-0 libmpcdec6 libobs0 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenmpt-modplug1
  libplacebo72 libproxy-tools libqt5svg5 libqt5x11extras5 libqt5xml5 libresid-builder0c2a libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libsdl2-2.0-0 libsidplay2
  libsndio7.0 libspatialaudio0 libssh2-1 libupnp13 libva-wayland2 libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore9 libxcb-composite0 obs-plugins obs-studio vlc vlc-bin vlc-data
  vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-access-extra vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-output
  vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
0 to upgrade, 58 to newly install, 0 to remove and 12 not to upgrade.
Need to get 21.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 98.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Note the number of `vlc` items, and also note the question at the very bottom.

As for whether you installed anything bad, the answer is "no". VLC is a fine tool for watching and/or converting videos.

Comment: makes sense.Thank you.I though why would obs-studio need something like vlc.
Btw, it's taking only 98 MB addition space in your system.In my case it was more than 250 MB.

Comment: I have a bunch of video packages installed already, so have fewer dependencies to download 